# 5000 item limit prevents opening item even if view works fine

Tags: list-view, task-list, list-view-threshold

I have a Sharepoint 2013 task list with 5001 items in it. I have talked with the department that uses it about limiting the size by clearing out old items, but that is probably a little ways off.

When I ran into the size limit, I increased the limit temporarily and added an index and then brought it back down to 5000. That worked fine to allow me to view the list. However, I could not open an item from the list to edit it unless the view threshold was brought back up above 5000.

What is the solution for this?

I should say that this particular list is used by about 10-15 people at a time, max.

Edit: Here is the exact error message that showed up in the Event Log.

> The form template failed to load. (User: 0#.w|domain\username, Form Name: Template, IP: , Request: https://home.domain.org/Units/unitname/SitePages/Home.aspx, Form ID: urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:list:-AutoGen-2014-10-24T20:13:58:284Z, Type: DataAdapterException, Exception Message: The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator.
>   The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator.)

Comment: Can you check the logs and copy the exact error details?

Comment: Can you paste the error when you try to open de item?

Comment: Just posted the details of the error message.

Comment: Is the list using a customized InfoPath form? The error seems to be indicating that a lookup (choice) field on the form is pulling up too many list items. If that's the case, you can filter the data source by some other field on the form (current user, for instance).

Comment: Omegacron, thanks for that insight. I did not create the list or any forms myself, but I will ask the person who did. Maybe this will get us on the right track.

Comment: Omegacron, you were exactly right. The person who created the form had for some reason included a value called "predecessors" which I suppose was meant to let you link a task to a previous task. It wasn't even displayed on the form anywhere. Once I deleted that, it worked as expected. Can you put your reply in an answer form so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 1):

In the past, I have just increased the list view threshold in Central Admin. I have an app running right now that is sitting at about 17000 items that's used approximately 2000 times per day, and haven't noticed a performance hit.

There's a great article written by Sharegate that addresses this issue: 
http://en.share-gate.com/blog/how-to-deal-with-the-5000-items-list-view-threshold

Answer (score 1):

The ideal solution in your case would be to create multiple views filtered on date created or modified columns or if you have another custom date column (One view per year). You would have to index these filter column though since you mentioned that you wanted to have the older items cleared. Creating views based on the status of the tasks is another option.

If not then you could define a retention policy for the list and archiving old items to another list.

Regards

Comment: Hey, as I said in the summary I already have the view itself down well below the 5000 item limit. In this case, it is at around 20-30 items in the filtered view. The problem is opening up the actual item to edit it.